# Database Design: Multiple join tables or one table with identifying 'table' column

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm designing a database where any content can be tagged and I'm likely to want to be able to select all content with a specific tag.

I'm struggling with the following two options and would appreciate some advice. If there's a better way please let me know.

**Option A**
Multiple 'many to many' join tables.

```
tag:
  id
  tag

media:
  id
  title
  src
  creation

media_tags:
  id
  media_id
  tag_id

article:
  id
  title
  content
  creation

article_tags:
  id
  article_id
  tag_id
```

**Options B**
A single 'tag reference' table, which uses a 'table' column to identify which table to join to.

```
tag:
  id
  tag

tag_reference:
  id
  row_id
  tag_id
  table

media:
  id
  title
  src
  creation

article:
  id
  title
  content
  creation
```

From a maintenance point of view option B seems favorable but considering the SQL query to select all content and don't think it's possible without multiple queries.

Comment: I'd go with the first one. Storing table names as a column is not such a good idea; imho.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database. Your question is a specific instance of the general problem of inheritance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using **Option B**, you can't set up foreign keys to the other tables. Thus I would go with **Option A** and one table for each m:n relation.

"From a maintenance point of view option B" – is a nightmare. What happens if you delete an article? All the rows with that `row_id` will persist in `tag_reference` table. You always need to update those entries manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes complete sense. Option A is the winner

Answer (score 1):

Option B contains a multivalued dependency - and as such is breach of [4th normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form). I much prefer Option A

Answer (score 0):

Actually, It depends on every sql developer. But I prefer `Option A` since you can easily know that a certain column in a table is a `foreign key` (*assuming it's true*) of the other table.

`Option B` is somewhat bad design because storing table names in a column is bad idea. You can spend more `IF` or `CASE` here.

Answer (score 0):

The second option pretty much prevents you using any JOINs for efficient SQL, forcing you into using slow multiple selects.

So I would say the first option is far preferable.

Comment: Of course is it still possible to join the tables – even when using such a layout as in the **Option B**. Maybe it's not that efficient and you have to pass the table name as search parameter every time.

Comment: Only if you know in advance which table to join against, or join against all possible tables in the SQL.